# Given marginal pdfs of discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$. How to find the joint pdf?

Tags: probability

Given a marginal pdf of $X$ and $Y$ with
\begin{align}
P(X=-1) &= \frac{1}{3} \\
P(X=0) &= \frac{1}{2} \hspace{10mm} P(Y=0) = \frac{3}{5} \\
P(X=1) &= \frac{1}{6} \hspace{10mm} P(Y=1) = \frac{2}{5}
\end{align}
and $P(XY = 0) = 1$. Determine the joint pdf of $(X, Y)$.

I tried to solve this problem by formula of finding marginal pdf. I got six equations and six unknowns. After that, I solved the matrix and found these six unknowns. I hope you got the point of What I did because it is problematic for me to express it since English is not my native language.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are not independent and there is not enough information here to find the joint pdf.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, unless you've omitted some details, this is a pmf, not a pdf.

Second, we're given that $P(XY=0)=1$. Thus
$$P(X=1, Y=1) = P(X=-1, Y=1) = 0$$
Moreover, we conclude that if one variable is nonzero then the other must be zero. $P(X=0 | Y \neq 0) = 1$ and $P(Y = 0 | X \neq 0) = 1$. This lets us nail down
$$f(1,0) = P(X=1, Y=0) = P(X=1) = \frac 16$$
$$f(-1,0) = P(X=-1, Y=0) = P(X=-1) = \frac 13$$
$$f(0,1) = P(X=0, Y=1) = P(Y=1) = \frac 25$$
The one remaining outcome is $\{X=0, Y=0\}$, which assumes the rest of the probability: $$f(0,0) = P(X=Y=0) = 1-\frac 16 - \frac 13 - \frac 25 = \frac 1{10}$$